# node.js response in export module

Tags: node.js

I am learning node.js. I am trying to have an http response from within a module that is been called from my index.js

this is my index.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const SheetData = require('./sheetdata.js');

app.post("/", function(request, response) {
   // code
    GoogleAuth.myGoogleAuth(JSON.parse(content), SheetData.mySheetData);
   // code    
}
```

---

and this my module:

```
exports.mySheetData = function () {   
   response.json({ user: 'tobi' })
}
```

I keep getting the error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection 
(rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot destructure property `data` of
'undefined' or 'null'
```

Is response within the scope of the module? Is the promise been rejected because response is out of scope?

Thank you

---

This is my google auth, which is from tutorial node.js and google sheets. It is use only for authentication.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const fs = require('fs');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';


exports.myGoogleAuth = function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);
console.log("inside google")
  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}
```

my index.js is:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const SheetData = require('./sheetdata.js');
app.post("/", function(request, response) {
    GoogleAuth.myGoogleAuth(JSON.parse(content), SheetData.mySheetData);
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

my module:

```
exports.mySheetData = function (auth) {
    const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
    sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
      spreadsheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      range: 'A2:R',
    }, (err, {data}) => {
      if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      const rows = data.values;
      if (rows.length) {
          response.json({ user: 'tobi' })
      }}
```

I have tried passing response to module: 
GoogleAuth.myGoogleAuth(JSON.parse(content), SheetData.mySheetData(response));

and in module : exports.mySheetData = function (response, auth) {....

but is not working. I get error: authClient.request is not a function
.

Comment: Can You provide link to `GoogleAuth` that You're using?

Comment: Provide full code, problem is not in code that You shared

Comment: Is response within the scope of the module?  NO.   Is the promise been rejected because response is out of scope?   NO

Comment: I cannot recognize this method `GoogleAuth.myGoogleAuth` official google auth does not have it. so please provide the code of myGoogleAuth. also provide full code of question.  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` tells that there's somewhere promise was rejected. So in Your code I cannot see any promise.